# Virtualenv: pip install matplotlib==1.3.1: Problems with libfreetype and libagg

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, pip, virtualenv

I want to install a specific version of matplotlib (1.3.1) in a virtualenv. I created the virtualenv, activated it and ran pip install.

```
virtualenv env
. ./env/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib==1.3.1
```

Resulting in error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-UafI0m/matplotlib/"

**Solutions I tired:**

- Added sudo permission
- Upgrade setuptools (pip install --upgrade setuptools)
- Upgrade pip (python -m pip install --upgrade pip)
- Added the -Iv argument to pip (sudo pip install -Iv matplotlib==1.3.1)
- Installed ez_setup (pip install ez_setup), for ez_setup the pip install worked.

**Setup:**
Python 2.7.15rc1
Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

**Edit:** 
I tested it a with a bunch of other packages and was able to install all of them properly. The ultimate goal is to install s4d. I followed the instructions given [here](https://projets-lium.univ-lemans.fr/s4d/install.html). Under requirements matplotlib Version 1.3.1 is listed. However which would be a proper replacement for 1.3.1? Can I just upgrade to 1.4 ie.?

**Edit 2: Complete Output**

```
pip2 install matplotlib==1.3.1
Collecting matplotlib==1.3.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/d0/17f17792a4d50994397052220dbe3ac9850ecbde0297b7572933fa4a5c98/matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
                    python: yes [2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
                            [GCC 7.3.0]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.9.0]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.2]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.2]
                     pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                            not be found.]
                       png: yes [version 1.2.54]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.4]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for Tk (tk.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.25]
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: yes [version 0.62.0]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Ji6dpj/matplotlib/
```

**EDIT 3: libfreetype2 and libagg**
So we narrowed it down to libfreetype missing (and libagg). After the recent update to Ubuntu 18.04 I had many issue with the font rendering. So I downgraded freetype as suggested [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14290), with the following bash commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6=2.8-0.2ubuntu2.1
sudo apt-mark hold libfreetype6
```

I checked if freetype is installed with (which it is)

```
ldconfig -p | grep freetype
```

So I unmarked freetype6 and ran update, upgrade and dist-upgrade, and then checked if I could install matplotlib, resulting in the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this? **Do I have to edit something in the pkg-config?**

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libfreetype6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
source env/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib==1.3.1
```

**Edit 4 / Preliminary Solution** 
The package libfreetype6-dev (sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev) helped, so now the setup.py / pip finds the libfreetype. However the new error I am facing is. But that is probably a new question

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Is there no other information provided about the error? Usually I would expect a whole bunch of stuff printed in case the install fails.

Comment: I can edit the whole output in the post if that helps, but no the error message is just that

Comment: Could it be related to libfreetype6 ? I recently upgrade my Ubuntu to 18.04, which resulted in troubles rendering fonts. Because of that ran sudo apt-get install libfreetype6=2.8-0.2ubuntu2.1; 
sudo apt-mark hold libfreetype6  Which fixed the font rendering issue for me (issue descired [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14290))

Comment: Well, that output tells you indeed that `"The following required packages can not be built: * freetype"`. You need to install freetype first.

Comment: I checked with: ldconfig -p | grep freetype and it states freetype is installed

Comment: As a matter of fact pkg-config --list-all | grep freetype doesnt return any results

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just install matplotlib1.4 and try if s4d works? It might be that the installation guide was not updated since newer matplotlib versions came out.

Comment: yes I tried and posted the result. It still fails, but it's getting clearer why. I think the problem are the library libagg and freetype6. I am still not quite sure how to fix it

Comment: in the link you shared before it states in Python packages for s4d:
The following packages are required to use S4D.
You can install them on your own or follow the procedure
described in the Quick guide using virtualenv. - pandas - pyAudio - scikit-learn. So if you don't want SIDEKIT then you maybe don't need those packages?